# Number of zeros of a power series

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Consider the infinite series
$$f(z) = 2\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k z^{(2k+1)^2} -1.$$
I want to show that $f$ admits one zero in the interval $(0,1)$ (in $\mathbb{R}$).

I have perfect knowledge about the nature of zeros for $z$ away from 1, since I can approximate it by truncating the series. However, the truncation does not work well as $z\to 1^-$.

I am thinking to use techniques in complex analysis. One possibility is to apply Rouche's theorem, by comparing $f$ with function $g$ like $g(z)=2z-1$ for $z > 0.5$. However I have difficulty showing the condition $|f(z)-g(z)|<|f(z)|+|g(z)|$.

What possible approach one can attempt to say something about the nature of zeros as $z\to 1^-$?

The following figure shows the plot of the function $f$
[[image: <span class=]$f(z)$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azwcd.png)

I also have the following guess: $f(z)<-1+2z-z^4$ for $z$ close to 1, which will help me to see the nature of roots.

Comment: The series is convergent only for $|z|<1.$

Comment: Yes. But I want to know more about the zeros in the interval $(0,1)$ when $z \to 1^-$. As far as I know, $f(z)\to 0$ as $z\to 1^-$.

Comment: This reminds me [theta function](https://users.ox.ac.uk/~quee4127/theta.pdf), but I'm not sure how to express $f(z)$ in terms of theta function due to the presence of sign change.

Answer (score 2):

If you consider the function $$f_n(z) = 2\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k z^{(2k+1)^2} -1$$ there is a root close to $z=1^-$ only if $n$ is odd. If $n$ is even, close to $z=1^-$ there is a positive local minimum value but no root.

To *estimate* the root, what you can do is to let $z=1-\epsilon$, expand
$$(1-\epsilon )^{(2 k+1)^2}=\sum_{p=0}^\infty (-1)^p \binom{(2 k+1)^2}{p}\epsilon^p$$ truncate to some order, perform the summation, consider that it is a trucated series to some order and use series reversion.

For example, performing the above summation up to $p=5$ and $k=3$ leads to
$$g(\epsilon)=4-168 \epsilon +3024 \epsilon ^2-41616 \epsilon ^3+449304 \epsilon ^4-3920280
   \epsilon ^5+O\left(\epsilon ^{6}\right)$$
$$\epsilon=-\frac{g(\epsilon)-4}{168}+\frac{(g(\epsilon)-4)^2}{1568}-\frac{467 (g(\epsilon)-4)^3}{5531904}+\frac{66781
   (g(\epsilon)-4)^4}{5576159232}-\frac{11456513
   (g(\epsilon)-4)^5}{6557563256832}+O\left((g(\epsilon)-4)^6\right)$$ SInce we want $g(\epsilon)=0$, the *estimate* is
$$\epsilon=\frac{283507943}{6403870368}=0.0443$$ while the exact solution is $\epsilon=0.0433$.

What it *seems* is that
$$f_{2m+1}(z)=0 \quad \implies \quad z\sim 1-\frac 1 {25 m}$$ Starting with such estimate, Newton method would converge quite fast.

Trying for $m=10$ (which corresponds to a polynomial of degree $1849$), Newton iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
q & z_q \\
 0 & 0.996000 \\
 1 & 0.998004 \\
 2 & 0.997554 \\
 3 & 0.997211 \\
 4 & 0.997049 \\
 5 & 0.997022 \\
 6 & 0.997021
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for your calculations. Actually I have shown using PDE methods that the function should have no root near 1, but I want to show it using other methods, because I am considering a function that can be expressed in terms of $f$. In particular, we have by Tauberian type theorem that $\lim_{z\to 1^-} f(z)=0$ and $\lim_{z\to 1^-} f'(z)=-1$.